# The COUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created formula

```
RRC SR < 98% = CALCULATE(COUNT(x_TOPN_new_daily[RRC Setup Success Rate] <98))
```

to measure value less than 98 on column RRC Setup Success Rate but it gives error "The COUNT function only accepts a column reference as an argument.", Do u have any idea?

| City | RRC Setup Success Rate |
| --- | --- |
| B | 100​ |
| A | 96​ |
| C | 94​ |
| F | 95​ |
| R | 99​ |
| C | 97​ |

I want to get count result where less than 98

Answer (score 1):

Use this measure

```
RRC SR < 98% =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( x_TOPN_new_daily[RRC Setup Success Rate] ),
    x_TOPN_new_daily[RRC Setup Success Rate] < 98
)
```

Comment: It is working, thank you. what is the difference of mine and yours? can you explain?

Comment: COUNT doesn't accept a filter condition but a column reference only and CALCULATE needs both an expression (aggregation) and a filter condition. If my answer solved your problem you should "accept" it, so that others know.

Comment: can we add one more condition? if yes could you pls make example

Answer (score 0):

```
RRC SR < 98% = 
CALCULATE(
      COUNT(x_TOPN_new_daily[RRC Setup Success Rate])
     ,FILTER(x_TOPN_new_daily, x_TOPN_new_daily[RRC Setup Success Rate]<98)
)
```

An alternative solution.